# Angular i18n will work on AngularJS 1.5?

Tags: angularjs, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

Does i18n or ngx-translate work on Angular 1.5 (below Angular2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngx-translate works with angular2 and above. However you can use

https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate

with angular 1.x versions

Comment: Sajee, Can I take like ngx-translate will not work on Angular 1.5?

Comment: Thanks. But I don't see version specific info in that. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Viswa its just angularjs doc, it says everything

Answer (score 2):

For angular 1.x version can use
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-translator

Comment: That's Fine Pradnya. But I don't see my question answered.